# ¿Cómo ordeno alfabeticamente una palabra en PHP?

Tags: php

Suponiendo que tengo una variable con el valor: `"PRODUCTO PRINCIPAL"`.

Quisiera saber como ordenar este string alfabéticamente, luego de aplicar un `preg_replace` para unir ambas palabras y que quede una sola, es decir, que quede algo asi:

Pasar de esto ----- "PRODUCTOPRINCIPAL"
A esto ------------ "ACCDIILNOOPPPRRTU"

He intentado con:

```
$ordenar = str_shuffle("PRODUCTO PRINCIPAL");
```

Pero la misma devuelve un orden aleatorio y no alfabeticamente.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y ganes tu primer medalla. Para que tu pregunta no termine cerrada, te aconsejo que la [edit] y agregues el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de conseguir lo que quieres.

`str_split` : Convierte un string en un array.

`sort`  : Ordena un array.

`var_dump :` Muestra información sobre una variable

`implode` : podemos convertir un array en una cadena de texto de una manera rápida y eficaz.

```php
$pablabra = "PRODUCTOPRINCIPAL";
$letras = (str_split($pablabra));
sort($letras , SORT_REGULAR);
var_dump($letras);
```

resultado

```html
array (size=17)
  0 => string 'A' (length=1)
  1 => string 'C' (length=1)
  2 => string 'C' (length=1)
  3 => string 'D' (length=1)
  4 => string 'I' (length=1)
  5 => string 'I' (length=1)
  6 => string 'L' (length=1)
  7 => string 'N' (length=1)
  8 => string 'O' (length=1)
  9 => string 'O' (length=1)
  10 => string 'P' (length=1)
  11 => string 'P' (length=1)
  12 => string 'P' (length=1)
  13 => string 'R' (length=1)
  14 => string 'R' (length=1)
  15 => string 'T' (length=1)
  16 => string 'U' (length=1)
```

Ahora unimos el array

```
$respuesta = implode($letras);
var_dump($respuesta);
```

Resultado

```
string 'ACCDIILNOOPPPRRTU' (length=17)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funcionó perfecto, no sabía como terminar de cerrarlo.

Comment: Como complemento: `str_split` no funcionará en el caso de que la frase tenga acentos u otros caracteres no estándares al inglés. En ese caso usar `mb_str_split`. Una vez ordenados, estos caracteres quedarán al final de la cadena.